# Is it possible to install the ExpressionEngine admin interface on another server than the main one?

Tags: javascript, php, expression, expressionengine

I have a website created using ExpressionEngine Framework. I want to know if it is possible to have the admin inteface a server other than the main one. If yes, please explain how to implement this.

Comment: just letting you know about our proposal for an EE specific site here (if you already are supporting it, you need to link your account so your reputation counts towards it) http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46387/expressionengine

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a few things in mind, and yes I have done this for clients.

a) Database server privileges have to be setup to allow main web servers (in our environment there are always at least two web servers behind F5 load-balancers) and your "admin" web server access to the same database as they all need access to data in the single EE database.

b) Your web server(s) and your "admin" server need to be able to access the same file structure, in our environment this would be NFS mount-points on redundant head Netapp storage systems, but any type of NFS or true shared file system like GlusterFS, etc. As any file changes, uploads, save templates as files, etc. all need to be seen by all of the web/admin server(s).

Have seen a few reasons to set up this type of configuration.

a) Allows you to still login to the admin interface if your main/public web server(s) are handling too much traffic, are overload, etc, and removes processing of things like files uploaded, via the admin server off the public web servers.

b) Lock down administration access completely from the public Internet, setup the "admin" server behind a corporate firewall, allowing internal administration and publishing to EE.

In any case this is really no different than using admin.php normally, but again needs to be setup correctly so all web servers have access to the same files, and same single database/db server.

Answer (score 3):

I'm curious if it's technically possible, e.g. I'm thinking you might be able to do it if you can mount the original server as a drive/volume and have a custom Control Panel module that limits access based on something like the domain. But the site might be associated with a particular domain so I don't know if it will just break or if you can hack away at things to get it to work... Can't really say. You could prevent access on the server side as well, e.g. in your virtual host or htaccess or whatever config on the original server just cut off access to the Control Panel and on the other server cut off all access to content asides from what's in the Control Panel (though I'm not sure how this would work, if the CP is reliant on things you need public...).

I don't know if this would lead to any problems with licensing either.

It should all be possible, the question is how much work / hacking away is involved, what caveats you would run into (conflicting with add-ons, how CI/EE works...) and how much of that is okay/feasible with your situation.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible. If you are wanting to have the admin interface on a separate domain you could look at using MSM. But separate server, not currently possible.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not - your templates and system files must live on the same server (though your database could be located on a different server).